# Google Apps - Restrict email access outside of the office domain

Tags: monitoring, domain, g-suite

We use Google Apps as our primary email service provider.

We would like to monitor/restrict users who are accessing their Google Apps accounts outside of the organization's local domain (outside of the office)

Any ideas of how this can be achieved?

Comment: "restrict users who are accessing their Google Apps accounts" By that, are you referring to Restrict Login or Restrict sending email from the Google Apps account?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a premium account (Google Apps for Business, Education, or ISPs), is it possible by using the SSO. More details [here](http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=60224).

As I have read, google apps will not do this. But, they offer you the feature to allow your SSO application to manage the access and permissions.

So, you can authenticate users from an AD and in the SSO to verify the IP of the user and limit access if is not in a specified range.

Comment: Hi Paul, 
Yes we have a premium account.

Thanks for the quick response. Will Google's built-in SSO functionality be able to sync users with the AD? Or would we require a 3rd Party SSO application to have this feature in place?